# If $V$ is a vector space of dimension $n$ and $T: V → V$ is a transformation of V with $T ^ 2 = 0$, then $\text{rank }(T) ≤n / 2$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space of dimension $n$ and  $T: V → V$ be a linear transformation of $V$ with $T ^ 2 = 0$.  Prove that $\text{rank }(T) ≤\frac{n }{ 2}$.

That's my homework and really I'm awful at this.
Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Hint: Rank-nullity theorem, what can you say about the relation between $\operatorname{im} T$ and $\operatorname{ker} T$?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Let $\alpha\in V.$ Then $T(\alpha)\in \text{range}( T).$
Since $$T^2(\alpha)=T(T(\alpha))=0 \\
\implies T(\alpha)\in \ker (T).$$ Thus, $\text{range} (T)\subseteq \ker (T).$ So that $\text{rank}(T)\leq\text{nullity}(T)$.

Now, by Rank-Nullity Theorem, we have
$$\text{rank}(T)+\text{rank}(T)\leq\text{rank}( T) + \text{nullity}( T)=n$$
Hence, we must have $\text{rank}( T)\leq n/2.$

Answer (score 0):

$T$ has a non trivial kernel.  Lets say the dimension of the kernel of $T = m$

That means that there exist $m$ independent vectors in $V$ that are getting flattened  (mapped to the zero vector) when we apply $T(V)$.  When we apply the transformation a second time, no more than $m$ vectors in the image of $T(V)$ get mapped to the zero vector.

The rank of $T = n-m.$
The rank of $T^2 \ge n-2m.$
The rank of $T^k \ge n-km.$

It is given that the rank of $T^2 = 0.$  What does that say about $m$ relative to $n$?